# Prevent View from Snapping Back after Keyframe Animation Finished

Tags: swift, core-animation

I have a view which I am animating in such a way that it expands and moves to a new set of coordinates in the View Controller. I am doing this using Keyframes:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModeCubic, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {

        //Moving main View
        tappedView.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenSize.width/2)-250, (self.screenSize.height/2)-250, 500, 500)

    }
}, completion: nil)
```

The problem is that once the animation is completed, the view returns to its original position and size.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue if one is using auto layout. In which case, the final coordinates must be put in the completion handler for it to work.

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModeCubic, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
        // Moving main View
        tappedView.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenSize.width/2)-250, (self.screenSize.height/2)-250, 500, 500)
    }
}, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
    tappedView.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenSize.width/2)-250, (self.screenSize.height/2)-250, 500, 500)
})
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeCubic, animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
        // Moving main View
        tappedView.frame = CGRect(x: (self.screenSize.width/2)-250, y: (self.screenSize.height/2)-250, width: 500, height: 500)
    }
}, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
    tappedView.frame = CGRect(x: (self.screenSize.width/2)-250, y: (self.screenSize.height/2)-250, width: 500, height: 500)
})
```